# Why can't I change the Qvariant value inside a QMap?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qvariant

I'm trying to pass an object called `QMap<QString, QVariant>* collect_row` and then I'm going to fill the `second` element with a `QVariant` value. The current value in the `second` element is `0`.

I'm using this code to connect to a database and then copy the row from the database into the `QMap<QString, QVariant>* collect_row`.

```
DATABASE_STATUS Database::get_row_from(const QString& table_name, const QString& at_column_name, const QString& where_value_is_equal_to, QMap<QString, QVariant>* collect_row){
    /* Check if we are connected */
    if(!getInstance()->qSqlDatabase.isOpen())
        return DATABASE_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED;

    QSqlQueryModel qSqlQueryModel;
    qSqlQueryModel.setQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table_name + " WHERE " + at_column_name + " = '" + where_value_is_equal_to + "'");
    QSqlRecord record = qSqlQueryModel.record(0);
    QList<QString> column_names = collect_row->keys();
    QList<QVariant> values_holders = collect_row->values();
    for(int i = 0; i < column_names.length(); i++){
        QVariant value_holder = values_holders.at(i);
        value_holder.setValue(record.value(record.indexOf(column_names.at(i))));
    }

    return DATABASE_STATUS_OK;
}
```

So here I have the `column_names` and I want to set `QVariant` values into the `values_holders`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < column_names.length(); i++){
    QVariant value_holder = values_holders.at(i);
    value_holder.setValue(record.value(record.indexOf(column_names.at(i))));
}
```

I want to write this code instead, but I cannot write `values_holders.at(i).setValue()` because that function does not exist.

```
for(int i = 0; i < column_names.length(); i++)
    values_holders.at(i).setValue(record.value(record.indexOf(column_names.at(i))));

database.cpp:72:30: error: no matching member function for call to 'setValue'
qvariant.h:560:23: note: candidate function template not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const QVariant', but method is not marked const
```

So that means I cannot change the element, even if there is a function called `.setValue`?

Comment: I haven't used Qt in a while, but I wonder if things like `QList<QVariant> values_holders = collect_row->values();` and `QVariant value_holder = values_holders.at(i);` are making copies of the values from the map and list respectively and you are modifying those copies instead of the objects in the map.

Comment: @RetiredNinja So you mean that they are not sharing the same memory?

Comment: You are probably coming from Java or C# background. But this is C++. C++ has value semantics, not reference semantics. You must learn to use references. Which will take you a while, I guess. Switching completely the mindset from reference semantics to value semantics is quite difficult.

Comment: IIRC Qt is Copy-on-Write, as Qt predates C++11. Qt detach & containers semantics always used to give me a headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code. Note that I changed the `QMap` pointer to reference. I believe the code should work though I have not tested it. But it is still super-ugly and very non-optimal. But I tried to do just minimal changes to your provided code.

```
DATABASE_STATUS Database::get_row_from(const QString& table_name, const QString& at_column_name, const QString& where_value_is_equal_to, QMap<QString, QVariant>& collect_row)
{
    /* Check if we are connected */
    if(!getInstance()->qSqlDatabase.isOpen())
        return DATABASE_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED;

    QSqlQueryModel qSqlQueryModel;
    qSqlQueryModel.setQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table_name + " WHERE " + at_column_name + " = '" + where_value_is_equal_to + "'");
    QSqlRecord record = qSqlQueryModel.record(0);
    QList<QString> column_names = collect_row.keys();
    for(int i = 0; i < column_names.length(); i++){
        QString column_name = column_names.at(i);
        collect_row[column_name] = record.value(record.indexOf(column_name));
    }

    return DATABASE_STATUS_OK;
}
```